# Settings icon deleted accidentally from iPod touch

Tags: ipod-touch

I was just walking around with my iPod Touch and touched the screen accidentally. The settings icon was deleted and I can't recover it. It's very weird because usually you can't delete default apps icons.

I can't find it in iTunes either after connecting and sync iPod with iTunes.

I would prefer not to lose my current settings like bookmarks in Safari, mail settings, etc.

The iPod is not jailbroken and I would prefer not to jailbreak it.

Accessing the settings panel is enough, I don't really need the icon.

Comment: The same thing happend to my granddaughter it took me forever but I did find it in her utility's click the utility's if you'll look at the bottom of the utility's their are more then one dot swipe it to the left hope this helps

Comment: There is another little weird way. Call Siri and tell her to open Settings app. In settings, go General -> Reset -> Reset Homescreen Layout and confirm action.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you certain you didn't just accidentally put it in a folder? It's impossible to delete, as you note.

You can determine if the app is still there by sliding springboard to the right until the spotlight search pane is revealed. Type "settings" and if the app is still installed it will appear in the search results; tapping on the result will launch it.

If it still shows up in spotlight then it's there on your device somewhere. The other possibility, if it's not in a folder or you're otherwise just missing it, is that all 11 springboard pages are full of app icons and you somehow accidentally moved your Settings app to the 12th page or beyond. In that case, group some apps into folders and, if necessary, sync with iTunes, at which time the icon will become visible again.

Comment: Hi. Yeah a folder called "Utilitarios" (Tools in English) was created (I didn't do it) and the icon is in there. Thanks. I didn't had any folder before (except games, automatically created by iOS) so it didn't occur to me. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't have enough points on this site to vote you up. I usually hang around in webmasters.stackex...

Comment: @Osvaldo Check the checkmark next to the answer to accept it. That's more important than voting it up, and you don't need to have any reputation to accept an answer to your question.